# Is this an alright way to design a DB schema for a task scheduling application?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, sql-server-ce, database-schema

I'm making a to-do list thingy in my spare time for learning etc. I'm using **SQL Server Compact 3.5** along with **Entity Framework** for data management. It is a desktop application, meant to be used by a single person.

I have close to no knowledge with database stuff, and am focusing my energies more on the UI side of things.

I was going along merrily implementing CRUD of tasks, when I thought it would be nice to have some scheduling for the tasks. Begin task in future, repetitions daily/weekly/monthly/yearly/custom etc.

I went on to try to design my DB to accomodate this with my limited knowledge and poof, I end up with like 14 new tables. I then searched online and found posts pointing to [sysschedules on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx). All accomplished in one table. I lowered my head in shame and tried a puny attempt to improve my design. I got it down to 10 tables while including some stuff I liked from the sysschedules table.

This is my (simplified) schema now(explanation below image):
[image: Task scheduling database schema]

A **Task** can have a **SchedulingInfo** associated with it.
I forced OO into this, so SchedulingInfo is an abstract type which has various 'subclasses'.

`TimeOfDayToStart_Ticks` represents the time to start... since I don't want to store it as a datetime.

**The subclasses:**

- **CustomSchedule**: Used to allow a task to run some day, or a **set** of days, in the future.
- **IntervalSchedule**: eg. Run everyday, or every 3 days, or every 4 hours, etc.
- **Monthly/Yearly-Schedule**: **Set** of days to run every month/year
- **MonthlyRelativeSchedule**: I stole this from the sysschedules thing. Holds a **set** of days that conform to things like every second(Frequency) Saturday(DayType), or the last weekday of the month, etc. (See previously mentioned link to see full explanation).

My code will retrieve a list of ScheduleInfo, sorted by `NextRun`. Dequeue a ScheduleInfo, instantiate a new Task with relevant details, **re-calculate** `NextRun` based on the subclass of ScheduleInfo, save the ScheduleInfo back to the DB.

I feel weird about the number of tables. Will this affect performance if there are like thousands of entries? Or is this just like yucky design, full of bad practices or some such? Should I just use the single-table approach?

Comment: Well, if some on chances upon this question say, in a few years, feel free to answer it then >_>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your table flood will have a negative impact on performance. If `YearlySchedule` and the other stuff are derived entities from the base entity `SchedulingInformation` and you have separate tables for base and derived properties you are forced to use **Table-Per-Type** inheritance mapping which is known to be slow. (At least up to current version 4.1 of EF. It is announced that the generated SQL for queries with TPT mapping will be improved in the next release of EF.)

In my opinion your model is a typical case for **Table-Per-Hierarchy** mapping because I see four derived entity tables which only have a primary key column. So, these entities add nothing to the base class (except their navigation properties) and would only force unnecessary joins in queries.

I would throw these four classes away and also the fifth - `IntervalSchedule` - and add its single property `Interval_Ticks` to the `SchedulingInformation` table.

The four `...Specifiers` tables could all refer then with their foreign keys to the `SchedulingInformation` table.

So, this would result in:

- Five tables: `SchedulingInformation` and 4 x `*Specifiers`
- One abstract base entity: `SchedulingInformation`
- Five derived entities: `*Schedule`
- Four entities: `*Specifier`

Each of the `*Schedule` entities (except `IntervalSchedule`) has a collection of the corresponding `*Specifier` entity (one-to-many relationship). And you map the five `*Schedule` entities to the same `SchedulingInformation` table via Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance mapping.

That would be my primary plan to try and test.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. I did not know about the EF+TPT performance issue :(. I read more about it. I'll go with your TPH suggestion, though I feel weird about the multiple-personality disorder of the table. But I guess that's just my inexperience with DB stuff, with me trying to force OOP & "type-safety" into databases.

Comment: @ForeverLearnNeverMaster: Here is a blog post about TPT performance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx Yes, I also don't like TPH that much and would prefer TPT, but the price for TPT is currently too high (.NET 4.5 will probably fix the performance issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/25/generated-sql-improvements-for-tpt-queries.aspx The final release of the "June CTP" mentioned here will go into .NET 4.5).

Comment: Follow-up query. I've gone and implemented it as suggested, but I was wondering if there was a way to enforce that each Specifier type is only associated with the proper ScheduleInfo subclass? Right now, after I instantiate say, a `MonthlySchedule`, it is possible to add to its `MonthlySpecifiers` as expected, but **also** to its other entity-collections, eg. `YearlySpecifiers`. That is, `YearlySpecifiers` can be associated with `MonthlySchedules` since the `*Specifier` FKs point to the base `ScheduleInfo` class :(

Comment: @ForeverLearnNeverMaster: Yes, in the database such nonsense could be created (if you modify table rows manually or write into the DB without EF). But your EF model should represent the right constraints, say: `MonthlySchedule` has only a `MonthlySpecifiers` collection but not any other, so you can only associate a `MonthlySpecifier` with a `MonthlySchedule` *in your model*. If it's getting unclear ask better a new question.

Comment: Yah, I figured it out :D. In the EDM, I deleted all 4 generated ScheduleInfo-*Specifier associations (thus deleting respective navigation props). Then I created new associations between each derived type and its respective Specifier. (Right-click, Add->Association). Finally made sure the associations mapped to the proper ID fields, and all done :). Thanks for all the help, mang!